# how to match all the strings having a particular pattern between two other strings using regex

Tags: regex

I want to extract all strings from "Timestamp:" to "Parameter"

If I encounter any String ending with "Exception:" between "a\n" to "site" where '-' is the character preceding "\nTimestamp"

Input:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Timestamp: 8/10/2017 3:11:53 AM

Message: System.ArgumentNullException: site parameter is missing from distributed cache namespace
Parameter name: site
```

Output:

Timestamp: 8/10/2017 3:11:53 AM

```
Message: System.ArgumentNullException: site parameter is missing from distributed cache namespace
```

Basically, I want to detect any Exception in my .log file and show the Timestamp when that exception occured. Would be happy if the regex works from the Windows Command Line. Thank you.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me, I suggest you to update it by adding the desired output

Comment: Thank you. I edited it. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
(Timestamp.*\n*.*Exception.*\n*)(?=Parameter)
```

which would capture your result in the first group, see the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/J3KkJI/1)

Comment: Thank you. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that'll capture the timestamp and the message content in capture group 1 & 2 :

```regex
/^Timestamp:\s*(.*)$\s*Message:\s*(.*)$/gm
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/xTVLQi/3)

Example of powershell running the regex on the command line for a file "test.txt":

```
powershell -Command "$f=[io.file]::ReadAllText('test.txt'); $f |Select-String '(?m)^Timestamp:\s*(.*)$\s*Message:\s*(.*)$' -AllMatches |%{$_.Matches}|%{$_.Groups[1].Value+': '+$_.Groups[2].Value}"
```

Comment: Wow! People are so lovely. Thanks a ton mate!